# What are the cases where NPX is needed?

Tags: npm, npx

What I want to know is if I really need to use `npx` and would like to know in what cases does `npx` makes a difference comparing to just running the command.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think it becomes handy when you just want to test something:

- how does a certain library behave (eg. `npx storybook`)?
- how fast and what is the behaviour of my frontend build (eg. `npx angular-http-server -p 4200 --ssl --path dist`)?
- reproduction of a problem with a specific version;

To name just a few use-cases.

Do you *really* need to run `npx`? No you haven't, but I think you have to play around with it to develop an instinct when it's useful and when it's not.